# write multiple lines in a file in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
print "I'm going to write these to the file."
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

Here target is the file object and line1, line2, line3 are the user inputs.
I want to use only a single target.write() command to write this script. I have tried using the following:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

But doesn't that put a string inside another string but if I use the following:

```
target.write(%s "\n" %s "\n" %s "\n") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

The Python interpreter(I'm using Microsoft Powershell) says invalid syntax.
How would I able to do it?

Answer (score 49):

You're confusing the braces. Do it like this:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Or even better, use `writelines`:

```
target.writelines([line1, line2, line3])
```

Comment: ok using %(line1, line2, line3) outside target.write() makes them unavailable..  but where's the second "

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by `using %(line1, line2, line3) outside target.write() makes them unavailable`?

Comment: @kartikey_kant: `%` is an operation on the string, not the write call. The way you had it, you were telling Python to write a string with `%s` in it, then apply the `%` operator to the result of the `write` call.

Comment: It means I was writing target.write() %(line1, line2, line3)

Comment: yeah @user2357112 that what i meant by using %(line1, line2, line3) outside target.write() makes them unavailable

Comment: @kartikey_kant Ah i see what you meant by the first comment. Sorry, that was a typo!

Comment: Works for me, but you need to remove the spaces in between the placeholders or your output will have leading spaces on the second and third new lines. Didn't know about writelines, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Note that writelines doesn't add line endings.

Comment: Yes bran.io is right. If you want correct formatting you should instead write: target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))

Answer (score 12):

another way which, at least to me, seems more intuitive:

```
target.write('''line 1
line 2
line 3''')
```

Answer (score 7):

```
with open('target.txt','w') as out:
    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
    line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
    line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
    print("I'm going to write these to the file.")
    out.write('{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(line1,line2,line3))
```

Answer (score 3):

I notice that this is a study drill from the book "Learn Python The Hard Way". Though you've asked this question 3 years ago, I'm posting this for new users to say that don't ask in stackoverflow directly. At least read the documentation before asking.

And as far as the question is concerned, using `writelines` is the easiest way.

Use it like this:

```
target.writelines([line1, line2, line3])
```

And as alkid said, you messed with the brackets, just follow what he said.

Comment: `writelines` doesn't add line endings.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this as well:

```
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want a space at each new line use:

```
print("I'm going to write these to the file")
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

This works for version 3.6

Answer (score 1):

this also works:

```
target.write("{}" "\n" "{}" "\n" "{}" "\n".format(line1, line2, line3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `join` method of Python strings.

```py
target.writelines("\n".join([line1, line2, line3]))
target.write("\n")
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join :

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

Answer (score -2):

```
variable=10
f=open("fileName.txt","w+") # file name and mode
for x in range(0,10):
    f.writelines('your text')
    f.writelines('if you want to add variable data'+str(variable))
    # to add data you only add String data so you want to type cast variable  
    f.writelines("\n")
```