# How to make this code simply which uses argv, raw_input(), f.write() in Python

Tags: python

What I Want:

- write lines to file
- simply code
- It's ok if code don't need argv or some others

  Here is my code:

  ```
  from sys import argv

  script, file_name = argv

  target = open(file_name, 'w')

  while True:
      line = raw_input()
      target.write(line)
      target.write("\n")
      if line.strip() == '':
          break
  ```

I found two question about it, but I'm a new learner with Python and I don't know how to  combine the logic from the answers in these  related questions.

[write multiple lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019942/write-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-python)

[Raw input across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664443/raw-input-across-multiple-lines-in-python)

Hope I express clearly.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the code? Does it work? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Are you not getting output written in file? You are closing your file right?

Comment: It can write lines to file, but I'm not sure about closing file right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work but if you want to use *writelines* and the *iter* logic from both [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664675/2141635) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020007/2141635), you can use a for loop with  `iter(raw_input,"")` which will loop until an empty string:

```
from sys import argv
script, file_name = argv

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(line+"\n" for line in iter(raw_input,""))
```

`iter(raw_input,"")` behaves link an infinite while loop, it will keep asking for input until the user just hits return, [file.writelines](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm) takes an sequence of strings to write which we pass using a a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

If you were to use file.write, you just loop over the `iter(raw_input, "")` again and write in the loop:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    for line in iter(raw_input, ""):
        f.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to only write then this code should be fine.This code takes the file name from user and then writes the data into file line by line. Execution stops when there is no data entered by user.

```
file_name = raw_input("Enter the file name")
target = open(file_name, 'w')
while True:
     line = raw_input("enter data")
     target.write(line)
     target.write("\n")
     if line.strip() == '':
         break
target.close()
```