# Is there a simple way to write multiple lines to a text file?

Tags: python, text-files, writetofile

I'm writing this bookstore program that reads a text file, you place your order, and then it writes your receipt to a different text file. I wrote the whole thing forgetting I needed to write the receipt to a separate file. What is the best/easiest way for me to write this **entire** module to another file?

```
def receipt():
    sum=0.0
    print("\n\n")
    print("*"*70)
    print("\tThank you {} for your purchase at The Book 
    Store!".format(name))
    print("*"*70)
    print("\nQty\t\tItem\t\tPrice\t\tTotal\n")
    for i in range(len(myBooks)):
        print(myBooks[i][0],"\t",myBooks[i][1],"\t",myBooks[i][2],"\t\t",myCost[i])
    for number in myCost:
        sum = sum + number

    print("\n\nSubtotal:     ${}".format(sum))
    tax = round(sum * .076,2)
    total = round(sum + tax,2)
    print("Tax:          ${}".format(tax))
    print("Total:        ${}".format(total))
```

Comment: "What is the best/easiest way for me to write this ENTIRE module to another file?" - uh, what? I think you may have the wrong idea about what the word "module" means.

Comment: Do you mean to write all the things you're printing in the receipt file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write multiple lines in a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019942/write-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Aurora Wang- yes

Comment: U9-Forward if that is the same then I guess I just dont understand it. Would I need to clarify each one as "line 1","line 2", etc? or would it be more of pyhon already knows what I mean?? Im giving myself a headache!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this. I can't run your script because no variables are defined

```
output = receipt()
file = open("sample.txt","w")
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

Comment: I was so excited when I saw this! then I tried it and got this: file.write(output) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: OK!! So this did work!! The only thing I had to change was output= str(receipt()) for the very first line. THANK YOU!! I'm to new to upvote it otherwise I would've

Comment: Sorry, since the `receipt()` function doesn't return anything, this answer could not possibly work—not even with what @Cara, the OP, claims have fixed it by doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a string to contain all receipt information:

```
def receipt():
    str=''
    str += '\n\n'
    ....
    return str
```

Then you can call it like:

```
with open("bill.txt", "w") as bill:
    bill.write(receipt())
bill.close()
```

And I saw you also have some problems here are you doesn't push the `name` and `myBooks` to receipt(). Make sure it's not your problem when you run your script.