# Write multiple lines not working in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write multiple lines to the text file.

The code looks like this:

```
directory = 'C:\SPAN'
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'SPANscript.txt'), 'w') as OPATH:
    OPATH.writelines([r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\SGX.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cfe.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")), 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cme.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")), 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\hkex.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\Jsc%s_1700.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")), 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\CME_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\HKFE_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\OSE_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\SGX_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XCME_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XNYM_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                      'Calc',
                      r'SaveCalcSummary C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.csv' %(rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
                      r'Save C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.xml' %(rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
                      r'LogSave C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\logtest.txt'%rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")])
```

The data comes in one line like this, not sure why.

[image]

Followed this post: [write multiple lines in a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019942/write-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-python)
Need some guidance on this.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: @DDS, showed u my output.

Comment: you need to feed it a new line escape '\n' code at the end of each string

Comment: I suggest you to use Notepad++, so you can also see 'special characters' as CR and LF as in notepad are not clearly visible. Another thing is to post stuff as text instead of as pictures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the list of strings with `'\n'`:

```
OPATH.write(
    '\n'.join(
        [r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\SGX.%s.s.pa2' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cfe.%s.s.pa2' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cme.%s.s.pa2' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\hkex.%s.s.pa2' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\Jsc%s_1700.pa2' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\CME_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\HKFE_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\OSE_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\SGX_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XCME_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XNYM_Span_pos_%s.pos' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
         'Calc',
         r'SaveCalcSummary C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.csv' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'Save C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.xml' % (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")),
         r'LogSave C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\logtest.txt' % rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
    )
)
OPATH.write('\n') # write the trailing newline
```

Comment: This is far more pythonic than adding a fixed '\n' to every line by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add newline char to the string.

**Ex:**

```
directory = 'C:\SPAN'
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'SPANscript.txt'), 'w') as OPATH:
    OPATH.writelines([r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\SGX.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cfe.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n", 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\cme.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n", 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\hkex.%s.s.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\RiskFiles\%s\Jsc%s_1700.pa2'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n", 
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\CME_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\HKFE_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\OSE_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\SGX_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XCME_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Load C:\SPAN\Positions\%s\XNYM_Span_pos_%s.pos'% (rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + "\n",
                      'Calc' + "\n",
                      r'SaveCalcSummary C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.csv' %(rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n",
                      r'Save C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\%s.xml' %(rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),rundate.strftime("%Y%m%d")) + "\n",
                      r'LogSave C:\SPAN\Reports\%s\logtest.txt'%rundate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]) + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you didn't *tell* python to include a new line, so it's not doing it.

```
directory = 'C:\SPAN'
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'SPANscript.txt'), 'w') as OPATH:
    OPATH.writelines([r'some text here.', '\n', # this creates a new line
                      r'more text here.', '\n\n, # two new lines  
                      r'another line of text.', '\t'
                      # you can also create tab breaks/indents
                      ])
```