# Write a multi line string to a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write multiple lines of a string to a text file in Python3, but it only writes the single line.

e.g

Let's say printing my string returns this in the console;

```
>> print(mylongstring)
https://www.link1.com
https://www.link2.com
https://www.link3.com
https://www.link4.com
https://www.link5.com
https://www.link6.com
```

And i go to write that into a text file

```
f = open("temporary.txt","w+")
f.write(mylongstring)
```

All that reads in my text file is the first link (link1.com)

Any help? I can elaborate more if you want, it's my first post here after all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write multiple lines in a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019942/write-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: What does `print(type(mylongstring))` result in?

Comment: Please share your longstring variable how does it look.

Comment: Please share `print(repr(mylongstring))`.

Comment: Try this mylongeststring= `list(map(lambda x:x+'\n', mylongeststring))`. Now `f.write(mylongeststring)`.

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica I just get a whole bunch of <class 'str'>

Comment: @grag1337 Check my answer

Comment: @Amadan It just returns the same strings but with '' around them, e.g 'https://www.link1.com' compared to https://www.link1.com'

Comment: @A.L. That returns; write() argument must be str, not generator

Comment: So it's a _list of strings_, not a "multiline string". Those two things are completely different. Please make sure your question is correct.

Comment: @Amadan It's starting to look that way, my apologies.

Comment: @grag1337 you must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try closing the file:

```
f = open("temporary.txt","w+")
f.write(mylongstring)
f.close()
```

If that doesn't work try using:

```
f = open("temporary.txt","w+")
f.writelines(mylongstring)
f.close()
```

If that still doesn't work use:

```
f = open("temporary.txt","w+")
f.writelines([i + '\n' for i in mylongstring])
f.close()
```

Comment: Prints out the first string letter by letter

Answer (score 11):

never open a file without closing it again at the end.
if you don't want that opening and closing hustle use context manager with this will handle the opening and closing of the file.

```
x = """https://www.link1.com
https://www.link2.com
https://www.link3.com
https://www.link4.com
https://www.link5.com
https://www.link6.com"""

with open("text.txt","w+") as f:
    f.writelines(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved it for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'LinkWebsite'
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
with open("yourfolder\yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True, class_='Live'):
        link = a['href']
        f.write(link+"\n")
f.close()
```

Basically I had to "elevate" `f.write(link+"\n")` to the
"for" leaving it at the same height as "var" which is also created with the text wrapping function, if you don't want a line break just remove the `+"\n"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

data = []  # made empty list

data.append(mylongstring)  # added all the str values to empty list data using append

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Values']) # creating dataframe

df_string = df.to_string(header=False, Index= False)
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(df_string)  # Saving the data to txt file
```

Comment: Pandas is overkill for this. And why bother setting a column label if you're not going to use it?

Comment: `TypeError: to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Index'` The problem is `Index='False'` should be `index=False`.

Comment: This doesn't even work properly. It writes the string with escaped newlines. Maybe you meant `pd.DataFrame(mylongstring.split('\n'))`. But still, Pandas is overkill for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).