# How do i put text on a separate line with python file systems?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a program that will put the output of the user into a text file. What I want to do is have the text printed on multiple lines, not the same line. For example, if the UserName variable is set to "User":

```
UserName = input('What is your name?: ')


with open('Results ' + UserName, 'w') as WriteFile:
    WriteFile.write('Results for ' + UserName)


with open('Results ' + UserName, 'a') as WriteFile:
    WriteFile.write(' If this text is shown on another line, it means this was a success.')
```

The output would be:

> Results for User If this text is shown on another line, it means this
> was a success.

How could I make the output say:

> Results for User
>
> If this text is shown on another line, it means this was a success.

Comment: You insert a newline character, `\n`.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello! I voted to close this question because the solution seems pretty minor, I couldn't find a suitable duplicate but the info you needed is findable for instance [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019942/write-multiple-lines-in-a-file-in-python) has it being done in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UserName = input('What is your name?: ')

with open('Results ' + UserName, 'w') as WriteFile:
    WriteFile.write('Results for ' + UserName + "\n"+ "\n"+ 
         'If this text is shown on another line, it means this was a success.')
```

You can add a newline to your file by using '\n'.